# How to avoid Sympify to drop parentheses automatically

Tags: python, sympy

Let's say I have the following string

```
str1 = "a*(-d*(b+d)+d*(e*f))"
```

If I sympify it the result is

```
a*(d*e*f - d*(b + d))
```

But I don't want that Sympy drop those parenthesis. I want the final expression to be

```
a*(d*(e*f) - d*(b + d))
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a [known bug](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/4596). That same bug in the [google code archive](https://code.google.com/archive/p/sympy/issues/1497).

If you follow the google code archive link, you'll find a patch that possibly fixes your issue.

Other than that, there's not much you can do. The issue's status is still `open`

There's also this [pull request](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/12440) that you might find interesting, since it presumably fixes the issue.

Comment: That PR was merged, but it only concerns the distribution of a constant factor over addition. Keeping parentheses in `d*(e*f)` is not within its scope; this is about associative property not the distributive property.

Comment: This is not the same issue. That is about automatic distribution of constants over addition, not reassociation of products.

Comment: @asmeurer hmm weird that OP accepted it. Perhaps we both misread the *known* bug? I'll delete if OP agrees.

Comment: @math4everyone - agreed to delete the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Products in SymPy are automatically flattened.

You can manually avoid this with `Mul(..., evaluate=False)`, like

```
a*(Mul(d, e*f, evaluate=False) - d*(b + d))
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I need to match this expression again later on to get their coefficents where this method is giving me different outputs every time I run the program