# How in sympy Disable unnecessary parenthesis?

Tags: sympy

Tell me please, How to forbid to open brackets? For example,
8 * (x + 1) It should be that way, not 8 * x + 8
Using evaluate = False doesn't help

Comment: Hello Andrew, were you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, SymPy will convert the expression to its [internal format](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html), which includes some minimal simplifications. For example, sqrt is represented internally as Pow(x,1/2). Also, some reordering of terms may happen.

In your specific case, you could try:

```py
from sympy import factor
from sympy.abc import x, y

y = x + 1
g = 8 * y
g = factor(g)
print(g)  # "8 * (x + 1)"
```

But, if for example you have `g = y * y`, SymPy will either represent it as a second power (`(x + 1)**2`), or expand it to `x**2 + 2*x + 1`.

PS: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48530973/12046409) by SymPy's maintainer for some possible workarounds. (It might complicate things later when you would like to evaluate or simplify this expression in other calculations.)

Comment: Thanks, it's closer!

Answer (score 2):

The global `evaluate` flag will allow you to do this in the most natural manner:

```
>>> with evaluate(False):
...  8*(x+1)
...
8*(x + 1)
```

Otherwise, `Mul(8, x + 1, evaluate=False)` is a lower level way to do this. And conversion from a string (already in that form) is possible as

```
>>> S('8*(x+1)',evaluate=False)
8*(x + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `sympy.collect_const(sympy.S("8 * (x + 1)"), 8)`?

In general you might be interested in some of these expression manipulations: https://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/simplify/simplify.html

Comment: Thanks, with a string data type it is. But if this expression is y = x + 1. multiply it by 8. g=8*y. We get g=8*x+8 instead of g=8*(x+1)

Comment: After getting `g=8*x+8` do `g = sympy.collect_const(g, 8)`.

Comment: If we do not know by what number we will multiply? Maybe there is, as in Maxima, not a calculation?

Comment: What do you mean, "if we do not know"? Could you give some more context. I'm having an "xy problem" vibe... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem